# Bash (grep) regex performing unexpectedly

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a text file, which contains a date in the form of `dd/mm/yyyy` (e.g 20/12/2012).

I am trying to use `grep` to parse the date and show it in the terminal, and it is successful, 
until I meet a certain case:

These are my test cases:

- `grep -E "\d*"` returns 20/12/2012
- `grep -E "\d*/"` returns 20/12/2012
- `grep -E "\d*/\d*"` returns 20/12/2012
- `grep -E "\d*/\d*/"` returns ***nothing***
- `grep -E "\d+"` also returns ***nothing***

Could someone explain to me why I get this unexpected behavior?

***EDIT***: I get the same behavior if I substitute the `"` (weak quotes) for `'` (strong quotes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax you used (`\d`) is not recognised by [Bash's Extended regex](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html#sect_04_01_03).

Use `grep -P` instead which uses Perl regex (PCRE). For example:

```
grep -P "\d+/\d+/\d+" input.txt
grep -P "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}" input.txt  # more restrictive
```

Or, to stick with extended regex, use `[0-9]` in place of `\d`:

```
grep -E "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]" input.txt
grep -E "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}" input.txt  # more restrictive
```

Comment: -E did it for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use -P instead of -E which allows grep to use the PCRE syntax

```
grep -P "\d+/\d+" file
```

does work too.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` and `egrep`/`grep -E` don't recognize `\d`.  The reason your first three patterns work is because of the asterisk that makes `\d` optional.  It is actually not found.

Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: You got a +1 from me, because you explained to me what's wrong, but actually your alternatives don't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

To help troubleshoot cases like this, the -o flag can be helpful as it shows only the matched portion of the line. With your original expressions:

`grep -Eo "\d*"` returns nothing - a clue that \d isn't doing what you thought it was.

`grep -Eo "\d*/"` returns / (twice) - confirmation that \d isn't matching while the slashes are.

As noted by others, the -P flag solves the issue by recognizing "\d", but to clarify Explosion Pills' answer, you could also use -E as follows:

`grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]*/[[:digit:]]*/"` returns 20/12/

EDIT: Per a comment by @shawn-chin (thanks!), --color can be used similarly to highlight the portions of the line that are matched while still showing the entire line:

`grep -E --color "[[:digit:]]*/[[:digit:]]*/"` returns **20/12/**2012 (can't do color here, but the bold "20/12/" portion would be in color)

Comment: Good hint about using `-o`. Alternatively, use `--color` to highlight the matching text among the returned output.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It's a fantastic one. It's only a shame I get to accept only one answer.